# List-style goes away with inline-block - but I want my list decorators to stay

Tags: html, css, html-lists

How do I get them to stay?

I have the following list - the moment I add to my list `li` `display: inline-block;` the custom list decorators I designated disappear.

Is there a CSS way of keeping my list decorators when the list is horizontal, or are list decorators only ever supposed to appear with vertical lists? Of course I could just have an image next to every list entry, but for simplicity's sake I'd rather deal with this in the CSS.

```
.first-page-menu-list {
    list-style-image: url('../graphics/list-style-image.png');
    list-style-position: inside;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternate method consists of floating the `li` elements.

```
<ul>
    <li>the item</li>
    <li>the item</li>
    <li>the item</li>
</ul>

ul {
    overflow: auto; /* similar to clearing the floats... */
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/kBNVz/

Comment: this behavior is bizzare

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Just curious, bizzare in what sense?

Comment: why would li bullets disappear if i change their display type to anything else, and if i remember right it used to not be the case.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer If you change the display type of an `li` element, then the browser is not obligated to add list markers.  For example, if you enclose a `p` element in a `ul`, then you would not expect a list marker to appear to the left of the `p`.

Comment: that would be incorrect html. `ul` should have only `li` in it. `li` can have others. enclosing `p` in `ul` is wrong.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer it's the [`display:list-item`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) which adds the bullets. Change it, and the bullets are gone.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you're right but there's an easy fix for this, just use the background as long as you're not using it otherwise try this:

CSS:

```
.first-page-menu-list li {
    background: url('../graphics/list-style-image.png') no-repeat 0px 4px;
    display: inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="first-page-menu-list">
    <li>asd</li>
    <li>asdf </li>
    <li> asdf</li>
</ul>
```

Play with the px values and you'll easy see what does which magic

Comment: its useful in some conditions i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox works well for this without the need to clear your floats.

```
ul.inline-list-style {
  list-style: upper-roman;
  display: flex;      
}
ul.inline-list-style li {
  flex: 1;
}
```